# deleting two ranges of lines from multiple text files on Mac

Tags: macos, text, sed

On my MacBook Pro, I'm trying to delete two ranges from multiple files in a directory. Searching thus far, it seems like sed is a way to do it, but if I try to delete one of the ranges with the command:

```
sed -i '5825,6144d' *.tab.txt
```

I get the error message:

```
sed: 1: "cl9_408230953ref_f00507 ...": command c expects \ followed by text
```

Alternatively, I've tried other variants where the command seems to work (i.e., no error message), but the files haven't changed.  Suggestions?

Comment: See comment by waldyrious here... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131940/400632

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
sed -i '' '5825,6144d' *.tab.txt
```

Or

```sh
sed -i.bak '5825,6144d' *.tab.txt
```